# Java SessionDestroyed not called when session is inactive

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8, servlet-listeners

For testing purpose, I have made following entry in web.xml

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Now, The problem is that user is getting logged out after 1 minute of In-activity but The sessionDestroyed method of my Session Listener is not being called. How ever when I am logging out manually, every thing is working fine.

Is there any way that this can be handled?

Using Tomcat 8

Thanks in advance for Help.

Comment: what servlet container do you use?

Comment: How long did you wait before being impatient?

Answer (score 1):

According to the servlet spec 11.2.1 the `HttpSessionListener` is informed when

> an `HttpSession` has been created, invalidated, or timed out.

But you should not expect that the servlet container will immediately call `sessionDestroyed` after the timeout - it will use a background thread to periodically check session validity.

In your setup you should see the destroyed event, when you send a request to the server after the timeout and try to access the session. In this case the servlet container will check validity, call `sessionDestroyed` of the listener and return a null session.